# vscode install failed with "install failed error" on windows7

Tags: visual-studio-code

I try to install vscode on windows7 and get "install failed error", no detailed information, is there someone get the same error? It is crazy that vscode can not be  installed on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like 7Zip to extract the archived files to a VSCodeSetup folder, with the resulting files:

```
 Mode LastWriteTime      Length   Name
 ---- -------------      ------   ----
----- 4/22/2015 8:28 AM  140782   background.gif
----- 4/27/2015 6:22 PM  60255967 Code-0.1.0-full.nupkg
----- 4/27/2015 6:22 PM  74       RELEASES
-a--- 4/30/2015 9:25 AM  1911     SquirrelSetup.log
----- 4/24/2015 11:12 AM 1492992  Update.exe
```

Then open PowerShell (a CMD window would also work). I cd'd into the VSCodeSetup folder and ran the following command:

```
PS>.\Update.exe --install=.
```

(You may need to run PS or the CMD window as Administrator)

Referenced post: [VSCode Installation Failed - Failed to extract installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967953/vscode-installation-failed-failed-to-extract-installer)

Comment: It didn't work, the installation interface flashes and goes away.