# VSCode Installation Failed - Failed to extract installer

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

```
VSCodeSetup.exe
Installation has failed
Failed to extract installer
```

I am unable to install or open up the Setup Log.

Trying to install on Windows 8.1 Enterprise

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just downloaded VSCodeSetup.exe and the installation failed with an error dialog when I ran it on Windows 7.1 SP1.

I then right clicked on the VSCodeSetup.exe file and used 7Zip to extract the archived files to a VSCodeSetup folder, with the resulting files:

```
Mode           LastWriteTime       Length Name
----           -------------       ------ ----
-----     4/22/2015  8:28 AM       140782 background.gif
-----     4/27/2015  6:22 PM     60255967 Code-0.1.0-full.nupkg
-----     4/27/2015  6:22 PM           74 RELEASES
-a---     4/30/2015  9:25 AM         1911 SquirrelSetup.log
-----     4/24/2015 11:12 AM      1492992 Update.exe
```

I then opened PowerShell (a CMD window would also work). I cd'd into the VSCodeSetup folder and ran the following command:

PS>**.\Update.exe --install=.**

Installation completed successfully and Visual Studio Code opened.

Hope this helps.

Rick

Comment: That was it! I was on the same path. Even extracted with 7zip and tried Update.exe --install=Code-0.1.0-full.nupkg  The splash screen would flash and then go away.

Comment: Did the install stick for you? This morning when I got into work I booted up and now its not working again when I try to just run it. What is conflicting?

Comment: Hi Mike, yes it is still working for me.  I have an "Open with Code" context menu item in explorer, and I also added the following to my $profile to add an alias to vscode if it is installed:

if (Test-Path $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Code)
{
 Set-Alias VSCode (resolve-path $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Code\*\Code.exe)
}