# VSCode ran once on install, won't run or install again

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running this on Windows 7 SP1 with most (if not all) current patches.  I have administrative permissions on this machine.

The first time I ran VSCodeSetup.exe, it ran the installer for several minutes then launched the actual application.

I got called into a surprise meeting, so I closed it thinking I'd look at it again later.

However, when I returned to my computer and tried to launch it, I found no evidence that it was actually installed... no desktop icon, no entry in the start menu, no Explorer integration...

I tried running `VSCodeSetup.exe` again, but all it does it show the installer screen for a split second, which then vanishes.

Since then, I've tried the suggestions outlined in [VSCode Installation Failed - Failed to extract installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967953/vscode-installation-failed-failed-to-extract-installer) to install the application, even going so far as to run `Update.exe --uninstall` followed by running VSCodeSetup.exe again, but nothing has worked.

I even tried disabling my antivirus software and running the installer again, to no avail.

Does anyone know what I can do to get VSCode working again?

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments and answers to [Install VSCode in a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013157/install-vscode-in-a-specific-folder), Visual Studio Code installs itself to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Code` on Windows.

While I'm not sure why it didn't register itself with Explorer, I can at least create a shortcut to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Code\bin\code.cmd` (with icon `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Code\app.ico`) to get it working again.

Or remove the directory entirely and run VSCodeSetup.exe to install it again, which still doesn't add Explorer integration... but this time at least the `PATH` now has code in it.

Answer (score 0):

On windows VSCode is installed as Code.exe and its located in your

`C:\Users\<windows-user>\AppData\Local\Code\app-<version-number>\Code.exe`

or

`C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.5.0\Code.exe`